# PS3 controller - SHANWAN

Tags: gamepad, ps3

I have a ps3 controller but I have the following problem:

- if I connect by USB it works but the controller never stop to vibrate
- I cannot manage to connect it via Bluetooth

`$ dmesg`

```
[ 3535.328372] input: SHANWAN PS3 GamePad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:054C:0268.0001/input/input16
[ 3535.329083] sony 0003:054C:0268.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Joystick [SHANWAN PS3 GamePad] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
```

- **How can I properly setup SHANWAN controller on Linux ?**
- Or  **Where I should I submit a bug report**

SHANWAN are not original controller but:

- they works fine on Windows
- they are most of not original controller are SHANWAN

Comment: What is shanwan? From a quick google, this is some kind of controller driver for retropi?

Comment: I think shawan is the producer of the controller. It is a ps3 dualshock compatible device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured out how to fix vibration on Ubuntu for Shanwan controllers attached to USB.

The fix was found here :
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1038906-start-0.html

File linux.../drivers/hid/hid-sony.c should be modified in kernel sources and kernel should be recompiled.

I've slightly changed it (to adapt for any Sony PS3 gamepad copy with producer "ShanWan" or "SHANWAN" - my version has capital names):

```
struct sony_sc {
    __u8 led_count;
 };

+/*
+ * The ShanWan reports the same id as the Sony SixAxis, therefore
+ * it can't be added to sony_devices[], but we still need to know which one
+ * we're dealing with.
+ */
+static int is_shanwan_gamepad(struct hid_device *hdev)
+{
+   return strstr(hdev->name, "ShanWan") || strstr(hdev->name, "SHANWAN) ;
+}
+
 static __u8 *sixaxis_fixup(struct hid_device *hdev, __u8 *rdesc,
               unsigned int *rsize)
 {

<..........>

static __u8 *sony_report_fixup(struct hi
    struct sony_sc *sc = hid_get_drvdata(hdev);

    /*
+    * The ShanWan  gamepades when used over USB, times out when
+    * initialising reports, but it works just fine without init.
+    */
+   if((sc->quirks & SIXAXIS_CONTROLLER_USB) && is_shanwan_gamepad(hdev))
+      hdev->quirks |= HID_QUIRK_NO_INIT_REPORTS;
+
+   /*
     * Some Sony RF receivers wrongly declare the mouse pointer as a
     * a constant non-data variable.
     */

<...........>

static int sixaxis_set_operational_usb(s
    /*
     * Some compatible controllers like the Speedlink Strike FX and
     * Gasia need another query plus an USB interrupt to get operational.
+    * The ShanWan gamepads doesn't like these additional steps.
     */
+   if(is_shanwan_gamepad(hdev))
+      goto out;
+
    ret = hid_hw_raw_request(hdev, 0xf5, buf, SIXAXIS_REPORT_0xF5_SIZE,
              HID_FEATURE_REPORT, HID_REQ_GET_REPORT);
    if (ret < 0) {
```

The kernel download and compile can be found here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel
after sources download, modify hid-sony.c accordingly and compile.

Comment: I sent back this joypad so I cannot test ... btw thx